# Matrix congruences

Tags: linear-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, matrix-congruences

If A, B are two integer square matrices of the same size such that $A\equiv B\pmod n$, is $A^p\equiv B^p \pmod{pn} $ for a prime p dividing n?

Comment: Just to make sure, the congruence of the matrix is defined componentwise, right?

Comment: Are you sure that this even holds for $1 \times 1$ matrices?

Comment: @YiFan yes. And sorry, I meant to assume that p divides n. I think it holds for 1x1 matrices in that case

Comment: Is $n$ arbitrary?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg But $2\not\mid3$...

Comment: @KentaS Arbitrary with only the assumption that $p\mid n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let $n=p=2$
let $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$
$A^2$ is the zero matrix and $B^2=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$
$A\equiv B\pmod{2}$ but $A^2\not\equiv B^2\pmod{4}$